# Литература по безопасности сетей и телекоммуникационных систем

Tags: книги, безопасность, криптография, voip

Из всего спектра предлагаемых книг в области обеспечения безопасности передачи данных я прочел "Прикладная криптография" Брюс Шнаер. Порекомендуйте правильную и полезную литературу по темам:

1. Обеспечение безопасности при использовании мобильной и VoIP связей
2. Современные методы защиты информации в телекоммуникационных сетях

Так же будут полезны хрестоматийная литература по сетевой безопасности в целом.